# Mapstruct! @Mapping with conditionQualifiedByName and expression parameters in one @Mapping

Tags: java, spring, mapping

I have a problem using both - condition and expression in single field mapping with @Mapping annotation. I need some simple solution to check incoming field on null and blank value.

I have 2 interfaces responsible for such checks.

```
@Qualifier
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
public @interface UtilConditions {
}

@UtilConditions
public interface StaticUtil {

    @Condition()
    @Named("isNotBlank")
    static boolean isNotBlank(String value) {
        return StringUtils.isNotBlank(value);
    }

    @Condition()
    @Named("isNotNull")
    static boolean isNotNull(Object value) {
        return value != null;
    }

    @Condition()
    @Named("isCollectionNotEmpty")
    static boolean isCollectionNotEmpty(Collection<?> collection) {
        return collection != null && !collection.isEmpty();
    }
}
```

That gives me an elegant way to check values.

For example

```
    @Mapping(target = "name", conditionQualifiedByName = "isNotBlank")
    @Mapping(target = "firstName", conditionQualifiedByName = "isNotBlank")
    @Mapping(target = "rateCurrency", conditionQualifiedByName = "isNotBlank",
        expression = "java(getCurrencyById(dto.getRateCurrency()))")
    public abstract Entity toEntity(EntityDto dto);

    public Currency getCurrencyById(String currencyName) {
        return currencyRepository.findById(currencyName)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException(Currency.class, currencyName));
    }
```

But Mapstruct doesn't allow to use condition and expression in one mapping, conditionQualifiedByName just ignoring.
Also i have tried to use different arguments in @Mapping annotation witch are responsible for conditions and expressions but unsuccessfully.

Please tell me how can i use isNotBlank() method from StaticUtil first, to prevent blank parameter passing to getCurrencyById() method.

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Cant't you just check for blank inside getCurrencyById() method?

Comment: @hermit No. In this case, I have to return something, but I need to leave the old value. I even can not use Uftermapping